# loading dataset into python using pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to load a data set from uci machine learning repository into python using pandas data frame.
 df=pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data',names=[ 'mpg','cylinders','displacement','horsepower','weight','acceleration','model year','origin','car name'])

But in the output names (headings for the columns) are not correctly aligned.Anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your column names contains some spaces in between there names like 'model year' so replace all the spaces with '-' using this code-:

```
#get all the column names and replace spaces with '_'
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
df.head()
```